# Using Tailwind Forms Plugin with React Select

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, react-select

I am trying to integrate `Select` from `react-forms` with tailwind css and the tailwind forms plugin (`@tailwindcss/forms`).

With only tailwind and react-select, the form renders correctly. However, with the plugin, an outline appears. I would like for tailwindcss forms not to interfere with `react-select` styling. Is there an effective solution to allow `react-select` styles to override tailwind plugins?

[image]

Additionally, please let me know if there are any effective solutions for styling `react-select` forms using `tailwind` without resorting to other libraries, like `emotion` or `styled-components`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can set the box shadow to none for the input when focused

```
<Select
....
styles={{
  input: (base) => ({
    ...base,
    'input:focus': {
      boxShadow: 'none',
    },
  }),
}}

/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks [@Bogdan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2633602/bogdan) for [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68475658/6920264), that indeed did the trick!

What comes to the author's second question, as of [version 5.7.0](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/releases/tag/react-select%405.7.0), React Select allows styling with classes through [the `classNames` prop](https://react-select.com/styles#the-classnames-prop). Here's an example of how it can be used (from their docs):

```
<Select
  classNames={{
    control: (state) =>
      state.isFocused ? 'border-red-600' : 'border-grey-300',
  }}
/>
```

I've recently styled React Select with Tailwind, and it worked as expected! I also used the `unstyled` prop to eliminate the default styling. Refer to the [list of available components](https://react-select.com/styles#inner-components) to target the parts you want to style. For what it's worth, I also wrote a [detailed article](https://www.jussivirtanen.fi/writing/styling-react-select-with-tailwind) on my implementation if that's of any help.

And oh, I also discovered an alternative method to override Tailwind forms plugin with the class styling approach. As the React Select `input` key targets the containing `div` of the actual `input` element, we can target the input element with Tailwind's [arbitrary variants](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#using-arbitrary-variants):

```
<Select
  classNames={{
    input: () => "[&_input:focus]:ring-0"
  }}
/>
```

I still prefer the original solution by Bogdan, though, as it's a bit clearer what's going on, but your preference may vary.

Answer (score 1):

> Additionally, please let me know if there are any effective solutions
> for styling react-select forms using tailwind without resorting to
> other libraries, like emotion or styled-components.

The answer to this is to use this library
https://github.com/ben-rogerson/twin.macro

Example, you can do something like this:

```
import tw from 'twin.macro';
import ReactSelect, { Props } from 'react-select';

const Styled = {
  Select: tw(ReactSelect)`rounded-lg text-center border-2`
};

const Select: React.FC<Partial<Props>> = (props) => {
  return (
    <Styled.Select {...props} />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the class strategy for the plugin, it will disable the extra styling, but you will need to implement the `form-*` class to every other input.

Here is the [documentation](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-forms#using-classes-instead-of-element-selectors) for it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way to remove the border if you are using custom class via `classNamePrefix`

```
<Select
    classNamePrefix="myselect"
    options={options}
/>
```

globals.css

```
.myselect__input {
  @apply focus:ring-0;
}
```

If you are looking for full styling tutorial, try read this awesome post https://www.jussivirtanen.fi/writing/styling-react-select-with-tailwind